# How to remove an app from recent apps list?

Tags: 9.0-pie, recents-screen

We have had the recent uninspired idea to let a SmartPhone upgrade itself to the "*Pie*" Version of the "*Google*" "*Android*" Operating System.

[image: The "_Software Information_" Pane]

Now, although everything went smoothly, we have discovered to our utter amazement that we are no longer able to close a Mobile Software Application at once. We are able only to close all of the running Mobile Software Applications at once.

[image: The "_Close All_" Pane]

No matter how much we have been searching so far, there is no obvious individual "*Close*" Button for each Mobile Software Application in this Latest Version.

Does anybody know how to close them individually, in a gentle way? We are not referring to any Forced Closures by means of terminating them.

Comment: Here: https://support.google.com/android/answer/9079646?hl=en from https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&ei=kNidXa-LJaG-vASJ4LuIBQ&q=google+support+android+close+apps+recents&oq=google+support+android+close+apps+recents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments the way to close individual apps in the Samsung One UI is to simply "swipe" that app away.

The two gestures I have here are swiping up on the app to close it or swiping down to maximise it.

Comment: Swiping doesn't actually *close* the app.